# Dividing a Data Frame or Matrix by a Vector in R

Tags: r, scale, normalization, division

This seems like it shouldnt be too difficult, but I am having a hard time with this.  Lets say for example I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(Names=rep(c('A','B'),5),
                   First = rnorm(10),
                   Second = rnorm(10),
                   Third = rnorm(10))
```

What I want is to divide the entire data frame by the average of A.  This I can calculate by:

> a.mean <- sapply(data[data$Names == 'A', 2:4], mean)

But when I try to divide the whole data frame by that vector like this I don't get the right values:

```
normalized.data <- data[2:4]/a.mean
normalized.data$Names <- data$Names
sapply(data[normalized.data$Names == 'A', 2:4], mean)

First     Second      Third 
0.2578018 -0.5864073  0.1156760
```

Wheras I wanted was for the normalized average of A to now equal 1.  Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Since you're never using the `B` data, let's get rid of it

Comment: Note the typo in the last line. You are calculating colmeans of the original data there and not of the normalized data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(Names=rep(c('A','B'),5),
                   First = rnorm(10),
                   Second = rnorm(10),
                   Third = rnorm(10))

a.mean <- sapply(data[data$Names == 'A', 2:4], mean)
data[,2:4] <- sweep(data[,2:4],MARGIN=2,a.mean,"/")

(norm.mean <- sapply(data[data$Names == 'A', 2:4], mean))
## First Second  Third 
##     1      1      1
```

Depending on your application, it might be easier to make the `Names` column be the row names instead:

```
data <- data.frame(First = rnorm(10),
                   Second = rnorm(10),
                   Third = rnorm(10),
                   row.names=rep(c('A','B'),5))
```

I also like `subset(data,Names=='A')` for readability (although it's not recommended for programming: see https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation )

Comment: Is there an advantage of using sweep, compared to a double transposed division?

Comment: I find it more readable, and it applies equally to row or column operations (by using `MARGIN=1` vs `MARGIN=2`, but I don't think there's much performance difference (it might even be marginally slower).

Answer (score 2):

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(Names=rep(c('A','B'),5),
                   First = rnorm(10),
                   Second = rnorm(10),
                   Third = rnorm(10))

a.mean <- colMeans(data[data$Names == 'A', 2:4])


normalized.data <- as.data.frame(t(t(data[,2:4])/a.mean))


normalized.data$Names <- data$Names
colMeans(normalized.data[normalized.data$Names == 'A', 1:3])

#First Second  Third 
#1      1      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, never mind:  you aren't dividing the way you think you are.  Dividing a matrix by a vector of values doesn't divide each column by a given value.

```
Rgames> foo
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    3    7
[2,]    5    3    7
[3,]    5    3    7
[4,]    5    3    7
[5,]    5    3    7
Rgames> foo/c(1,2,3)
         [,1] [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 5.000000  1.0 3.500000
[2,] 2.500000  3.0 2.333333
[3,] 1.666667  1.5 7.000000
[4,] 5.000000  1.0 3.500000
[5,] 2.500000  3.0 2.333333
```

Comment: Exactly, the divisor is recycled. That's why you can simply transpose foo to get the desired result.